# SelectCheckboxMenu - Disable "all-selection"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a *SelectCheckBoxMenu* (Primefaces component) with plenty of entries. However, the user is allowed to select max. 3 items. *SelectCheckBoxMenu* fullfils almost all my requirements, the only problem is that it offers the possibility to select all items, which i obviously don't need in this case.

Is there any possility to disable the "select-all" option? I am using an event to check the entries for max. 3. I think I could do the same for "select-all" and not allow him to select them, but **I don't want to have the "select-all" option** at all.

Below the code:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{services.titelId}" id="titel" 
            panelStyle="width:160px;" rendered="#{!services.isFirma()}"
            label="#{services.prepareTitel()}" style="width:160px;"
            styleClass="checkbox">
            <f:selectItems value="#{meta.getAkadTitelList()}" />
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{services.validateTitel()}"
                update="titel" process="@this" />
            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="titel" process="@this" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

In addition, the link to the primefaces-showcase example:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml

Comment: That thing is not a combobox. Your CSS class name is misleading and not self-documenting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I revised it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add css rule to your css file

```
#titel .ui-chkbox .ui-widget {
     display:none;
}
```

You should add `prependId="false"` to your `h:form` , or in case you don't want to add `prependId="false"` you can change the `#titel .ui-chkbox .ui-widget` selector into something like `#myForm\3A titel .ui-chkbox .ui-widget` (to handle the `:` id seperator)

---

In case you want the entire filter row removed you can set

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu filter="false"....
```

Comment: Thanks as always, I tried both options, but it didn't work. However, you brought me on the right way, css rule was the answer. I did "remove" the header from the checkboxmenu, which makes sense, it was what i needed. `.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header {
 display: none;
}` I changed the primefaces css because it makes sense for my project,  but if anyone else has the same issues, be aware, do it just for the selectboxmenu you need. Thanks again Daniel.

Comment: You better not change primefacs css , instead add this tule to your own css file and make sure it will be loaded last... so it will override primefaces css...

Comment: Oh sorry, I expressed myself badly, I didn't change the primefaces.css, i added this code in my own css.

Comment: You can also just use a classname. E.g. `<p:selectCheckboxMenu styleClass="without-selectall">` and then use `.ui-selectcheckboxmenu.without-selectall` instead of `#titel`. That's more reusable.

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to do it, this is what i was trying to say on my first reply: for anyone else, better use your own css declaration.

Comment: @BalusC your solution is not working in PF 6.2 as that class is not copied to panel...

Answer (score 19):

The previous answer did not work for me under PrimeFaces 5.0, so I took a deeper look in the generated HTML and found a solution for PF5 as well.

For **PrimeFaces 5.0** you can remove the "select all" checkbox like this:

```
.without-selectall .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header .ui-chkbox {
    display: none; 
}
```

Now use `panelStyleClass`-attribute instead of `styleClass`:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu ...
    panelStyleClass="without-selectall"
>
```

Comment: Simple and prefect solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add
<p:selectCheckboxMenu showHeader="false"......